# configuring squid proxy server ( won't connect, saying check proxy settings )

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

So I installed squid on an Amazon Ubuntu Server.

After hours of errors I was finally to setup properly to where I was getting errors when checking

"sudo service squid status" and "sudo du -sh /var/spool/squid"

I also ran "telnet localhost 3128" and I connect properly. It outputs

```
"Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'."
```

So I know that is running correctly.

But when I try to connect to my proxy via chrome, I cannot connect at all.

My squid.conf file looks like this

```
"acl network src 172.31.15.0/255.255.240.0


acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80          # http
acl Safe_ports port 21          # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443         # https
acl Safe_ports port 70          # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210         # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535  # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280         # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488         # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591         # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777         # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT

http_access deny !Safe_ports

http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost
http_access allow network

http_access deny all


cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 5120      16      256
refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico)$ 3600       90% 43200


http_port 3128

coredump_dir /var/spool/squid

refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern (Release|Packages(.gz)*)$      0       20%     2880
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320
"
```

And my ifconfig settings are as follows :

```
    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:d9:f6:3e:71:1f  
          inet addr:172.31.15.87  Bcast:172.31.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::8d9:f6ff:fe3e:711f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9001  Metric:1
          RX packets:61285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8446123 (8.4 MB)  TX bytes:5999460 (5.9 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2613 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2613 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:266006 (266.0 KB)  TX bytes:266006 (266.0 KB)
```

Comment: Since this is AWS - check your firewall/security settings and ensure you are allowed to connect from an external host. Test your telnet command from your client PC and see if that connects - if it does please `tail -f /var/log/squid/access.log` and see what it says

Comment: This helped. Thank you

Comment: can you confirm the IP address(es) you are connecting from? Your config indicates that `172.31.15.0 which is a private address - presuming your test machine is also not in the AWS cloud this may be your issue - you need to try the WAN IP/Network in your source list for allowed cache users.